# awk range need to be correct

Tags: awk

I need to check all number which starts from 2,3,7 or 8

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $19 ~/^[2-3]/ 
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $19 ~/^[7-8]/
```

I need to combine in 1 line like (it's incorrect, it just my try)

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $19 ~/^[2-3-7-8]/
```

How can I correct this ?

Comment: Just list the values in the bracket expression, you have no ranges, use `awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $19 ~/^[2378]/`

Comment: ... and ditch that `-F,`, just use `BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}`

Comment: A duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score -1):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $19 ~/^[2378]/
```

Comment: Can you give some more explanation?